# How can I use Glyphicons with JSF?

Tags: css, jsf

How can i use glyphicons with JSF(Netbeans: Maven/web application+JSF Framework)? I want to use a glyphicon with a `<h:link>`.

Here is how I did it in regular HTML:

```
<li><a href="home.xhtml" id="home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
```

Here is how that looked like:

[image]

Here is how I tried to do it in JSF:

```
<li><h:link id="bone" value="Home" outcome="book" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span></li>
```

Here is how it looked like:

[image]

As you can see, the glyphicon which is black and a little hard to see in that darkblue background color, is located down there. How do I make it to look like the HTML version but in JSF?

Ps, the "home button" is part of a navigation bar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use this code:

```
<h:link id="bone" value="Home" outcome="book" />
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span>
```

Your generated HTML code will be:

```
<a href="home.xhtml" id="home"></a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
```

Try like this:

```
<li>
    <h:link id="bone" outcome="book">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span>Home
    </h:link>
</li>
```

In short: the order you place the JSF code **matters**.